# C++0x 3d map initializing like in php associative arrays

Tags: c++, c++11, stdmap, uniform-initialization

i'm just getting into new c++0x stuff and instancing a map like this:

```
std::map<int, std::map<int, int>> foo;
foo[1][2] = 3;
```

is easily possible. But can i do something like in php?

```
$array = array(
    1 => array(
        2 => array(
            3
        )
    )
);
```

I'm not familiar with the syntax. Maybe something like this

```
foo[][][] = {
    1 {
        2 {3}
    }
};
```

So i dont have to write the index all the time:

```
foo[1][2] = 3;
foo[1][3] = 4;
foo[1][4] = 5;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using c++11 feature uniform initialization:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    // The value_type of a map is pair<const Key, T>.
    // To initialize a map an initializer list
    // of pair<Key, T> objects must be specified.

    // To initialize a pair:
    //
    std::pair<int, int> p{9, 10};
    std::cout << "pair:\n  (" << p.first << ", " << p.second << ")\n\n";

    // To initialize a simple map (no nesting)
    // with value_type of pair<int, int>:
    //
    std::map<int, int> simple_map
    {  // K  V
        { 5, 6 },
        { 7, 8 }
    };
    std::cout << "simple_map:\n";
    for (auto const& i: simple_map)
    {
        std::cout << "  (" << i.first << ", " << i.second << ")\n";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    // To initialize a complex map (with nesting)
    // with value_type of pair<const int, map<int, int>>
    //
    const std::map<int, std::map<int, int>> complex_map
    {  // K       V
       //       k  v
        { 1, { {3, 4},
               {5, 6} }
        },
        { 2, { {7, 8},
               {8, 8},
               {9, 0} }
        }
    };

    std::cout << "complex_map:\n";
    for (auto const& mi: complex_map)
    {
        std::cout << "  (" << mi.first << ", ";
        for (auto const& p: mi.second)
        {
            std::cout << '(' << p.first << ", " << p.second << ')';
        }
        std::cout << ")\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
pair:
  (9, 10)

simple_map:
  (5, 6)
  (7, 8)

complex_map:
  (1, (3, 4)(5, 6))
  (2, (7, 8)(8, 8)(9, 0))
```

See online demo at http://ideone.com/hCjtjP .

Comment: Thank you hmjd. Unfortunately i can't upvate you both, so i'm going to give the first poster the accepted answer. Sorry for that man! But anyway really appreciate your time!

Comment: I see you updated your post with some cool examples. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

you can use uniform initialization but it only works on initialization, not elsewhere.

```
std::map<int, std::map<int, int>> foo = {
    {1, {{2, 3}}}
};
```

notice the extra {}'s around the {2, 3}. to initialize a map you need an initialization_list of pairs. pairs are then constructed using uniform initialization as well.